# Check for first post using wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. Inside the loop I want to check if the post is the first result from the query.

This is my code.

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'home-slider', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'order' => 'ASC');
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>

<?php if (  ) { ?> // check if first post
    <p>TEST</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>TEST123</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the check inside the loop, you could move it to the outside and query the first post after an `if()` statement:

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'home-slider', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'order' => 'ASC');
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <p>TEST</p>

<?php
    endif;
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>

    <p>TEST123</p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This is kinda useless in real life usecases, where TEST vs TEST123 is not just a simple string but represents a complex template, that has a small difference somewhere. This solution would be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Try This code
First define `$inc=1;` out side the while loop

Then Check in while loop  `if($inc==1)` then print what you want and increment the $inc value using `$inc++;`

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'home-slider', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'order' => 'ASC');
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );$inc=1;
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>

<?php if ($inc==1 ) {$inc++; ?> // check if first post
    <p>TEST</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>TEST123</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The WP_Query object has a [current_post field, which is actually a counter](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/946ec8492fbde448af0a5441912a2267c12825f5/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L102-L108), counting from 0.

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'home-slider', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'order' => 'ASC');
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );$inc=1;
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>

<?php if ($query->current_post==0) { ?> // check if first post
    <p>TEST</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>TEST123</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
?>
```